# How to use passwords in encrypted vars-file (vault) in Ansible inventory?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm new to Ansible and struggle with Ansible vaults in combination with  inventory files.

What I want to achieve is a playbook that updates three machines. Two of these machines require a password (for `sudo`) so I can become root.

So here's my playbook...

```
---
- name: update all hosts, make sure default software is installed

  hosts:
    - vhosts
    - physical

  vars_files:
    - 'vars/main.yml'

  tasks:

    - name: Update apt cache
      apt: update_cache=yes

    - name: Upgrade packages
      apt: upgrade=dist
```

... and this is my inventory (filename `inventory`) with passwords still in plain text:

```
[vhosts]
10.0.0.1    ansible_user=root

[physical]
10.0.0.200  ansible_user=xxx  ansible_become=yes  ansible_become_method=sudo  ansible_become_pass=secretpassword1
10.0.0.201  ansible_user=yyy  ansible_become=yes  ansible_become_method=sudo  ansible_become_pass=secretpassword2
```

This is working fine.

Of cause I do not want `secretpassword1` or `secretpassword2` in the inventory. So I created a vault (stored in file `vars/main.yml` that looks like that:

```
---
- vars:
    pass1:secretpassword1
    pass2:secretpassword2
```

And I changed the inventory file to this:

```
[vhosts]
10.0.0.1    ansible_user=root

[physical]
10.0.0.200  ansible_user=xxx  ansible_become=yes  ansible_become_method=sudo  ansible_become_pass="{{ pass1 }}"
10.0.0.201  ansible_user=yyy  ansible_become=yes  ansible_become_method=sudo  ansible_become_pass="{{ pass2 }}"
```

Now when I try to execute the goodness with `ansible-playbook  update.yml -i inventory --ask-vault-pass` I receive following errors:

```
fatal: [10.0.0.200]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The field 'become_pass' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'pass1' is undefined\nexception type: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable'>\nexception: 'pass1' is undefined"}
fatal: [10.0.0.201]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The field 'become_pass' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'pass2' is undefined\nexception type: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable'>\nexception: 'pass2' is undefined"}
```

It seems like I was unable to define my variables correctly. But I have absolutely no clue how to do so. If anyone could give me a hand I'd be super happy. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Make your vault file look like this:

```
---
pass1: secretpassword1
pass2: secretpassword2
```

Your error:

1. You define variables in incorrect format inside YAML file.